# SQL Server comma-separated column to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, user-defined-functions

I currently have a table of three columns; `Org`, `Group ID` and `Role`.

[image]

The column called `Org` can be ignored.

What I have been trying to do is to group them based on `Group ID` and split each of the `Roles` that belongs to the same `Group ID` to a single column.

So far I could manage to group the records and put the `Roles` of the same group in the same column.

[image]

I used the following script:

```
Select 
    [Group ID],  
    Substring((Select ',' +  [Role] 
               From [dbo].[ASA_test] B 
               Where B.[Group ID] = A.[Group ID]] 
               For XML Path('')), 2, 8000) As List  
From 
    [dbo].[ASA_test]  A
Group By 
    [Group ID]
```

Later on I created a temp table variable and inserted the SQL above in it to use this variable in a user defined function afterwards to have the outcome.

Please see below:

```
DECLARE @MyTempTableVariable TABLE
(
    GroupID int,
    Role nvarchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTempTableVariable
   Select 
       [Group ID],  
       Substring((Select ',' +  [Role] 
                  From [dbo].[ASA_test] B 
                  Where B.[Group ID] = A.[Group ID]] 
                  For XML Path('')), 2, 8000) As List  
   From 
       [dbo].[ASA_test]  A
   Group By 
       [Group ID]
```

However I couldn't go any further as it didn't work as I expected.

Can someone please help? please note that the total number of records are not limited with what I post here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to specify the column name in your insert query after table name. See below:

```
INSERT INTO @MyTempTableVariable(GroupID , Role)....
```

Rest of the query should work fine.

Comment: if this works for you, please mark as answer so that other can also get benefits from this question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

do this.

```
SELECT  GroupID 
   ,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST([Role] AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
     FROM [dbo].[ASA_test] 
     WHERE GroupID  = t.GroupID 
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
    .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') List_Output
FROM [dbo].[ASA_test]  t
GROUP BY GroupID
```